# Unable to use Scipy.optimize.minimize 'SLSQP' due to 'Positive directional derivative for linesearch' or 'Constraint inconsistent'

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am struggling to solve a simple optimisation problem using scipy.optimize.mininize with 'SLSQP'

Apologies in advance I am not an expert but reading through some of the posts but apparently the message 'Positive directional derivative for linesearch' is thrown when SLSQP solver couldn't find a min (fast enough).

Appreciate if some one can advise if I am using incorrect solver for this problem, anyway I can get around the issue?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as sciopt

target=142
V=np.array([173.3, 5678.8,67898.98, 67898.0, 678987.0, 9876.87, 7659.9 ])
C=np.array([0.1,0.2,0.56,0.56,0.22,0.35,0.21])
L=np.array([1,1,0,0,0,0,1])
init_wts=np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0])

def min_cost(wts):
    return np.dot(C,np.multiply(wts,V))

def constraint1(wts):
    return np.dot(wts,V)-target

def constraint2(wts):
    return 0.2*target - np.dot(L,np.multiply(wts,V))

cons1 = ({'type': 'eq','fun': constraint1})
cons2 = ({'type': 'ineq','fun': constraint2})

bnds = tuple((0,1) for wts in range(len(V)))

sol =sciopt.minimize(min_cost, init_wts, method ='SLSQP', bounds=bnds, constraints=[cons1,cons2])
print(sol)
```

This produces following result:

```
fun: 0.0
     jac: array([1.73300000e+01, 1.13576000e+03, 3.80234288e+04, 3.80228800e+04,
       1.49377140e+05, 3.45690450e+03, 1.60857900e+03])
 message: 'Positive directional derivative for linesearch'
    nfev: 9
     nit: 5
    njev: 1
  status: 8
 success: False
       x: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

Comment: `Positive directional derivative for linesearch` I guess this is due to numerical-trouble and scaling your data might help (move towards 1, not 678987.0). But more important: analyze / debug (look at the values generated in these functions) the case where `'Constraint inconsistent'` is thrown as this is usually a very good indicator of a broken model (not a solver problem). Go for this first.

Comment: hi @sascha thanks a bunch!. As you suggested I scaled down my data to      V=np.array([173.3, 568.8,698.98, 698.0, 6787.0, 986.87, 759.9 ]) and it worked like a charm! I am trying to get my head round this and what I understood from your response is that the travel from initial values to a solution that met constraints, was either too far, rather the journey was too long for the solver. Am I right there and by scaling down the journey was made feasible, did I get that right? Also, is there any guidance around determining the max data i.e. what scaled down levels will be acceptable? Thanks.

Comment: Cannot tell you much more as this solver is rather arcane to me (multi-decade old fortran-code).Maybe scaling did the trick,but maybe it's just luck.In general howewer: everything in numerical-optimization is doomed by floating-point limitations (e.g. 1/3 cannot be expressed without error) and things get messy when solving systems of equations (to reason about search direction) and other parts.Every solver has some thresholds and those things are more often tuned to work for *normal problems* ~ small values around zero. I would guess, moving towards zero irt hessian is a good idea in general.

Comment: Additional remark: i also think that lots of people could be helped by moving away from scipy's solvers towards IPOPT (or commercials). In practice howewer, this is a big burden as there not too many easy-to-use libraries helping to use this one.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your help @sascha

Comment: @sascha Hey I don't really understand what scaling your data means could you please elaborate for me.